# What is the exact LINQ Query for this SQL Query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

i am very new in LINQ so,I can't understand what the exact `Linq` query is of this SQLquery.

Please give exact `Linq` Query similar to this SQL query.

```
Select  * From tblProduct 
Where ProductId In 
      (Select  ProductId  from  tblViewer Where ViewerId = 123)
```

Comment: help me i cant understand how to use **linqpad** as sql-to-linq converter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Contains` is the most straightforwrad way to implement an `IN` statement, so it would be something like:

```
tblProduct.Where(p => tblViewer.Where(v => v.ViewerId == 123)
                               .Select(v => v.ProductId)
                               .Contains(p.ProductId)
                );
```

Comment: @D Stanley ..can u say how to use **linqpad** as **sql** to **linq** converter

Comment: I don't think you can - you can see the SQL generated from a Linq statement but not the other way around.

Comment: yes, i can convert **linq to sql** but opposite can't using **Linqpad**